# Taming the MS Word Language Preference

Tags: ms-word

(This is not a strictly programming/coding kind of question, but it keeps you away from coding ...)

MS Word (2010) often *changes the proofing language* (supposed to be English) to a language I'm not using (German). This happens without apparent reason and without the "wrong" language anywhere in the document. The result is having the annoying red underline abound. I tried everything I, others, and documentation could think of, but it doesn't work:

- MS Word proofing language preference set to English
- MS Word editing language defaults to English
- MS Word display language defaults to English, highest priority
- MS Word help language preference defaults to English, highest priority (although most likely unrelated)
- MS Word itself is "English"
- OS "Format" is English (US) (Win7 Region Settings)
- OS "Location" is English (US)
- OS display language is English
- entire OS is English

The only thing which is not using English is my keyboard and the keyboard setting. It's German.

**What should I do to make MS Word forget about** German **temporarily?**

Not a solution:

- changing the keyboard hardware (I like to know where the umlauts are, and I still write texts in German. Do I get English when I want German then? ;))
- turning off proofing altogther (my typing error rate is considerable, and I read entire words missing the typos)
- uninstalling German language (I do use this language)

Solution could be:

- Say it's bug, can't do much about it :(
- Configure it correctly :)
- Any scripting/code/automation/VBA solution to get rid of German temporarily

Many thanks!

Did I mention I prefer Lyx/LaTeX/DocBook ... but alas, there are reasons

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would probably be this:
1. Find out where this setting is stored (search the registry).
2. Create a small program that changes the setting.
3. Create a shortcut for easy access to this program (or maybe a script that changes the setting before Word is started up).

Comment: I'm unsure whether this setting is being stored somewhere directly. Knowing which it would be actually is the issue. Otherwise I'd have to do diffs of the registry without knowing I'm gonna find something. This is too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you unchecked "Detect language automatically" in Review / Language / Set Proofing Language?

Comment: I already did. I noticed the language likes to change when I create a footnote (without having typed anything into it. This speaks against language detection as the source of the issue.

Comment: You may be right, but if automatic language detection is enabled, I'd suggest you disable it and see what happens.